# Bind Lookup Column with External Site's List in Infopath Form 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, sharepoint-foundation, custom-list, forms-services

Is this possible to bind datasource with dropdownlist of lookup column in Infopath form.

Means in my case :

i have one subsite : http://www.contoso.com/Marketing/Combraign

in this site having one list(Leads) with title contain each of company name.

and having another subsite : http://www.contoso.com/Testing

in this site contain List(Test). In this list i want to bind lookup field which coming reference from Leads list(from Combraign subsite). as lookup column its not possible to use external site with list.

but i have try to using infopath designer with dropdownlist and bind with datasource with sharepoint list or library like [`this`](http://msdnvietnam.net/blogs/quang/archive/2010/03/30/cascading-drop-down-list-in-sharepoint-2010-using-infopath-2010.aspx)

in CName Column field bind with datasource From Combraign(web)'s List(Leads) with title.

binding dropdownlist perfect in form.when submit data value not showing in Allitem.aspx page.

[image]

but in Editform.aspx and Dispform.aspx able to see bind value.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't open the referenced "like [this](http://msdnvietnam.net/blogs/quang/archive/2010/03/30/cascading-drop-down-list-in-sharepoint-2010-using-infopath-2010.aspx)" but from your question I understood that you building an Infopath form which you had not published, mispublished or disabled after publishing:

```
Editform.aspx and Dispform.aspx able to see bind value
```

Editform.aspx and Dispform.aspx are using the default (non-Infopath) Sharepoint form while after publishing your Infopath form onto a list, the Edit/Update, View/Display, Insert/New web pages, using, BTW, one and the same Infopath form of type/compatibility "**Sharepoint List form**"for all webpages should have been:

- **displayifs.aspx**  (instead of Sharepoint original default **DispForm.aspx**)
- **editifs.aspx** (instead of Sharepoint original default **EditForm.aspx**)
- **newifs.aspx** (instead of Sharepoint original default **NewForm.aspx**)

Also, it is impossible to publish Infopath "**SharePoint List Form**" type of form to more than one list less to multiple lists in different sites (Update: using non-modifiable **Main Data Connection**). And it is impossible to modify or choose manually Infopath "Sharepoint List Form" (the type you should see in Compatibility of "Form Options")

[image]

Update:
Sometimes, I am using the mixture of default Sharepoint web pages:

- **DispForm.aspx**
- **EditForm.aspx**
- **NewForm.aspx**

with Infopath form linked/injected web pages:

- **displayifs.aspx**
- **editifs.aspx**
- **newifs.aspx**

instead of either first 3 or the last 3, it is real pain in that place, requiring a lot of manual tossing after each form change.